# Impossible to use memory allocated to buffers with transparent huge pages (process killed)

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

I have 1TB of RAM, 900GB of which I need to allocate and use in a process (I have complete control on the hardware and I'm working on bare metal). I allocate 900GB of memory using `mmap()` (private, anonymous) and then use `madvise()` to set transparent huge pages on Fedora 37. The 900GB are then linearly filled with data.

This is not the actual program, but it gives the idea of the type of memory access:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    const uint64_t n = 900000000000ULL;
    char *p = (char *)mmap(NULL, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    madvise(p, n, MADV_HUGEPAGE);
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) p[i] = i; // Which data is immaterial
}
```

I can see the system allocating transparent huge pages as more memory is accessed. However, as soon as I get to the point where I'm allocating the memory currently used fom buff/cache (say, 300GB) the process is killed violently; even the shell is killed, and there is no reported signal. No message on `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg` (e.g., it does not seem a problem with the OOM killer).

It is not an overcommit problem: it is the same with `vm.overcommit_memory = 1`. I tried even `vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1000` to force Linux to free the pages for buff/cache. No results.

Moreover, if I replace the `mmap()` call with a standard `malloc()` everything goes through smoothly: the buff/cache memory is deallocated incrementally as the process touches more and more memory. It is specifically a problem with transparent huge pages (kernel bug?).

Presently I'm doing an `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` just before starting the program and in this way I can allocate and use almost all memory with transparent huge pages, but this can't be the right way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your program killed by a specific signal? Your example doesn’t include the `madvise` call; I can imagine what it would be, but could you include it?

Comment: I forgot the madvise() line, sorry. I edited the message. The process is just killed with the shell—no signal is reported.